Error in Flutter when displaying a video (chewie) at the top of a column, and an expanded webview below, only in release mode
I want to create a Flutter app with the following layout:

A column with two children:

At the top, a video player (chewie) at the correct aspect ratio
Below, a webview covering the remaining space



I used the following straightforward code which works OK when using it in debug mode, but crashes when I use it in release mode Specifically, it crashes when I switch to full screen mode or back.
Reproduce as follows:

create a main file as follows:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:temp_video_layout_test/video_player_widget.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const videoUrl = 'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-spinning-around-the-earth-29351-large.mp4';
const webUrl = 'https://google.com/';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _webViewController = WebViewController()..loadRequest(Uri.parse(webUrl));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text('demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              const VideoPlayerWidget(videoUrl),
              Expanded(
                  child: WebViewWidget(controller: _webViewController)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


Then add a video player widget as follows:

import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final String url;

  const VideoPlayerWidget(this.url, {super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerWidget> createState() => _VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {

  late VideoPlayerController videoController;
  ChewieController? chewieController;

  Future<ChewieController> loadVideoPlayer() async {

    //Initialize the controller:
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(widget.url);
    videoController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(uri);

    await videoController.initialize();

    //Initialize the Chewie controller:
    ChewieController chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoController,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ],
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: false,
      // zoomAndPan: true,
      aspectRatio: videoController.value.aspectRatio,
    );

    return chewieController;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadVideoPlayer().then((chewieController) => setState(() => this.chewieController = chewieController));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoController.dispose();
    chewieController?.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool videoReady = chewieController != null && chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized;

    return videoReady ? AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: Chewie(controller: chewieController!)
    ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}


Insert rewquired libraries (chewie, video_player, webview_flutter) in pubspec.yaml:

name: temp_video_layout_test
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.4 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  chewie: ^1.8.1
  video_player: ^2.8.6
  webview_flutter: ^4.7.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


I believe the error only occurs in Android.
To reproduce, you need to also add the INTERNET permission to AndroidManifest.xml.
Note that when I launch this app with flutter run on a real device it works OK.
But when I launch with flutter run --release it crashes as soon as I select the full screen option, or sometimes when I select it again to switch back to the non full screen mode.
Also the same code seems to work ok on iOS devices.

I discovered what the problem was: Because I am displaying a column, and the first child (video player) is in full screen mode, there is a crash because there is no space to draw the Expanded containing the web view.
Of course this does not explain why this happens only in release mode and only in Android. Perhaps there is an udnerlying bug. Or perhaps the error output should be more informative.
Either way, adding a condition to display the Expanded only when in portrait mode seems to fix the issue:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test')),
        body: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) => Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              const VideoPlayerWidget(videoUrl),
              Visibility(
                visible: orientation == Orientation.portrait,
                child: Expanded(
                  child: WebViewWidget(controller: _webViewController)
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }

